# Android support for AVRCP

Tags: android, bluetooth, avrcp

What Android versions and devices support AVRCP 1.3 and 1.4?

What is required from the app to support AVRCP 1.3 (provide track info)? We play audio via AudioTrack, not media player.

What is needed to support 1.4?

Are there any examples, source code, etc, that demonstrate how to support AVRCP 1.3 and 1.4?

Comment: Did you figure out an answer to this one?

Answer (score 0):

Base android does not support AVRCP 1.3/1.4, many other devices support (many phones support AVRCP 1.3/1.4 ex: Moto Razr series phones ) . Source code for AVRCP 1.3 can be found on the codeaurora git maintained by Qualcomm . 
AVRCP 1.3 need media information as STATUS, TrackName , ArtistName , AlbumName , Duration etc. check in AVRCP 1.3 spec version in bluetooth.org 
Also you will need to change the SDP record for the AVRCP profile to 1.3 .

Comment: Are there any examples with source code on how to implement 1.3 support in the app?

Comment: As in qualcomm codeaurora solution, changes are done in bluetooth framework and media framework. When any music starts, media fw broadcast intents to bluetooth fw ,these are "com.android.music.playstatechanged", "com.android.music.metachanged" ,"com.android.music.playstatusrequest",
"com.android.music.playstatusresponse". check in BluetoothA2dpService.java file in codeaurora. More changes are done in bluez stack to implement AVRCP 1.3 profile

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but non the less:
Profile support is dependent on Chipset and Stack.
The Bluetooth implementation have nothing to do with what Android version you are running.

The Qualified listings for devices can be found on Bluetooth.org
These listings contain supported profiles and profile version.

If a device uses the Bluetooth brand, it should be listed there.

Answer (score 0):

In Galaxy S9 I see in dev settings that 1.4 is the default but 1.5 and 1.6 are an option. My sony mex-n4100bt which claims to support 1.5 works out of the box to list files and stuff on Galaxy S4 of a friend. But doesn't work on my S9 before I start an app. Actually on my S9 only controls work and I couldn't find an app that supports browsing files. Need to spend a little more time investigating what is going on.

Back to the (old) question, I think one can use example supporting AVRCP in VLC codebase. But probably it is lower than 1.4 because with 1.4 browsing files should have been available.